# Why does boost::thread_specific_ptr freezes android ndk after a few seconds

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have an application using NDK to use a shared library with a java application.  The shared libraries use threads underneath and managing the AttachCurrentThread/DetachCurrentThread in the library is extremely awkward so I am attempting to use boost::thread_specific_ptr to create a class which manages the JNIEnv*.  The problem is if I use boost::thread_specific_ptr at all the application hangs after a few seconds.  Any suggestions?!?!

UPDATE: I added a second method which I believe is very similar under the hood but has the same problem.  Also have the gdb stacktrace:

```
boost::detail::thread_data_base::~thread_data_base() at thread.cpp:42 0x72e91b74    
boost::detail::thread_data<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf0<void, XXX>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<XXX*> > > >::~thread_data() at thread.hpp:91 0x72d69198    
boost::detail::thread_data<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf0<void, XXX>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<XXX*> > > >::~thread_data() at thread.hpp:91 0x72d691e4    
boost::checked_delete<boost::detail::thread_data<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf0<void, XXX>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<XXX*> > > > >() at checked_delete.hpp:34 0x72d69230  
boost::detail::sp_counted_impl_p<boost::detail::thread_data<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf0<void, XXX>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<XXX*> > > > >::dispose() at sp_counted_impl.hpp:78 0x72d72c54 
boost::detail::sp_counted_base::release() at sp_counted_base_spin.hpp:103 0x72c67480    
boost::detail::shared_count::~shared_count() at shared_count.hpp:371 0x72c67550 
~shared_ptr() at shared_ptr.hpp:328 0x72e91a3c  
boost::thread::join_noexcept() at thread.cpp:340 0x72e91a3c 
boost::thread::join() at thread.hpp:751 0x72cda274
```

The problem seems to lie in the destructor where i->_M_current is null, still working my way through the boost code to see what might be the real problem but it is slow moving.

```
  thread_data_base::~thread_data_base()
    {
        for (notify_list_t::iterator i = notify.begin(), e = notify.end();
                i != e; ++i)
        {
            i->second->unlock();
            i->first->notify_all();
        }
        for (async_states_t::iterator i = async_states_.begin(), e = async_states_.end();
                i != e; ++i)
        {
            (*i)->make_ready();
        }
    }
```

First Attempt

```
class ThreadJNIEnv
{

private:

    bool        m_bDetach;

    JNIEnv*     m_pJavaEnv;

public:

    ThreadJNIEnv( ) :
        m_pJavaEnv( NULL )
    {
        LOGI( "Attaching Thread" );

        g_pJavaVM->AttachCurrentThread( &m_pJavaEnv, NULL );

        m_bDetach = true;
    }

    ThreadJNIEnv( JNIEnv* pJavaEnv ) :
        m_pJavaEnv( pJavaEnv )
    {
        LOGI( "Attach (main thread): %p ", m_pJavaEnv );

        m_bDetach = false;
    }

    ~ThreadJNIEnv( )
    {
        if( m_bDetach )
        {
            LOGI( "Detaching Thread" );

            g_pJavaVM->DetachCurrentThread( );
        }
    }

    JNIEnv* GetEnv( ) { return m_pJavaEnv; };
};


// Class which manages JNIEnv per thread
boost::thread_specific_ptr<ThreadJNIEnv> g_oJNIEnv;

// Sample thread local data which also hangs the app
boost::thread_specific_ptr<int> g_oValue;

JNIEnv* GetJNIEnv( )
{
    // Do we already have a JNIEnv?
    ThreadJNIEnv* pJNIEnv = g_oJNIEnv.get( );

    if( pJNIEnv == NULL )
    {
        // Create a new JNIEnv (attach the thread)
        g_oJNIEnv.reset( new ThreadJNIEnv( ) );
    }

    return g_oJNIEnv->GetEnv( );
}

jint JNI_OnLoad( JavaVM* vm, void* reserved )
{
    g_pJavaVM = vm;

    g_pJavaVM->GetEnv( (void **)&g_pJniEnv, JNI_VERSION_1_6 );

    // This is a simple one that also exhibits the problem
    g_oValue.reset( new int[10] );

    // Add the main thread environment
    //g_oJNIEnv.reset( new ThreadJNIEnv( pJavaEnv ) );

    LOGI( "JNI_OnLoad called: vm=%p, env=%p", g_pJavaVM, g_pJniEnv );

    return JNI_VERSION_1_6;
}
```

Second Attempt

```
void DetachThread( )
{
    LOGI( "Detaching Thread" );

    g_pJavaVM->DetachCurrentThread( );
}

JNIEnv* GetJNIEnv( )
{
    JNIEnv* pJNIEnv = NULL;
    int status = g_pJavaVM->GetEnv( (void **)&pJNIEnv, JNI_VERSION_1_6 );

    switch( status )
    {
        case JNI_EDETACHED:
        {
            LOGI( "Attaching Thread" );

            g_pJavaVM->AttachCurrentThread( &pJNIEnv, NULL );

            boost::this_thread::at_thread_exit( DetachThread );
        }
        break;

        case JNI_OK:
        {
            // Everything is ok
        }
        break;

        case JNI_EVERSION:
        {
            LOGE( "GetEnv: version not supported" );
        }
        break;
    }

    LOGI( "GetJNIEnv: %p", pJNIEnv );

    return pJNIEnv;
}
```

Comment: Added working Android project which clearly exhibits the problem: https://github.com/dantwinkler/android-threading-jni.

Comment: Narrowed it down a bit more to just the boost thread join.  Working sample is located in: https://github.com/dantwinkler/android-threading-jni/tree/boost-thread

Comment: Have you tried enabling full CheckJNI? https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html#extended_checking

Comment: Looks like the problem is with the boost version I was using 1.53.  I compiled boost 1.49 with https://github.com/MysticTreeGames/Boost-for-Android and it seems to be working fine now.  The big question is what changed to break everything?!?!  I plan to do some diffs on the two but for now it's working...

Answer (score 0):

According to the stack trace, if I understood correctly, the destruction of the shared pointer, that contains the thread, starts from `join`, which seems rather weird. Your github code seems to me ok, but if the problem is with boost version, try to avoid shared pointer and use scoped_thread there or move construction.